# What is the formula to calculate the font-size for tags in a tagcloud?

Tags: algorithm, math, tags, tag-cloud

I have a tag cloud and I need to know how can I change the font-size for the most used tags.

I need to set a min-font-size and a max-font-size.

Comment: If you want the formula alone, the first question on the related sidebar should do fine for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378576/best-practice-with-tagclouds-or-tagcloud-logic

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use a linear or logarithmic assessment of the number of items associated with a certain tag relative to the largest tag, multiply it by the difference between minimum and maximum font sizes, then add it to the minimum font size. For example, the math in pseudocode might be:

```
let min = 12, max = 24
for each tag
    font = (items / items in biggest tag) * (max - min) + min
```

Comment: Similarly, for a logarithmic scale, you'd use `log(items) / log(items in biggest tag) * (max - min) + min`.  Conveniently enough, the base of your log does not matter.

Comment: I too would preferably use a logarithmic scale, otherwise if one tag is very popular, all the others will seem equal...

Comment: Thanks a million ... i have been searching for this through net and this is the simplest explanation i have found. Thanks again

Comment: @JustinL. I had to modify it to prevent division by zero if "items in biggest tag" equals 1. So (with variable name modifications) ~> `( maxcount>1 ? log(count) / log(maxcount) * (max - min) + min : min )`

Answer (score 6):

To make @Delan's answer more clear I created some examples in languages I am familiar with.

#### [Example in Javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/8LPsC/1/)

```
var tags =
[
    { Name: "c#", Uses: 100 },
    { Name: ".net", Uses: 75 },
    { Name: "typescript", Uses: 50 },
    { Name: "lua", Uses: 50 },
    { Name: "javascript", Uses: 25 },
    { Name: "jquery", Uses: 1 },
    { Name: "c++", Uses: 0 },
];

var max = 100; // Should be computed
var min = 0;   // Should be computed

var fontMin = 10;
var fontMax = 20;

for (var i in tags)
{
    var tag = tags[i];

    var size = tag.Uses == min ? fontMin
        : (tag.Uses / max) * (fontMax - fontMin) + fontMin;
}
```

#### Example in C#

```
var tags = new List<Tag>
{
    new Tag { Name = "c#", Uses = 100 },
    new Tag { Name = ".net", Uses = 75 },
    new Tag { Name = "typescript", Uses = 50 },
    new Tag { Name = "lua", Uses = 50 },
    new Tag { Name = "javascript", Uses = 25 },
    new Tag { Name = "jquery", Uses = 5 },
    new Tag { Name = "c++", Uses = 5 },
};

int max = tags.Max(o => o.Uses);
int min = tags.Min(o => o.Uses);

double fontMax = 20;
double fontMin = 10;

foreach (var tag in tags)
{
    double size = tag.Uses == min ? fontMin
        : (tag.Uses / (double)max) * (fontMax - fontMin) + fontMin;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<div data-i2="fontSize:[10,30]">
    <span data-i2="rate:1">A</span>
    <span data-i2="rate:4">B</span>
    <span data-i2="rate:7">C</span>
    <span data-i2="rate:12">G</span>
    <span data-i2="rate:5">H</span>
</div>
```

Then

```
i2.emph();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EUaC5/1/

Comment: it somehow seems to work and looks simple and perhaps useful but could you please explain all those magic words? (```rate```,```emph```,```[10,30]```) links to explanation elsewhere would be enough

Comment: Rate is here - http://i2ui.com/JavaScript/Properties#rate. i2.emph() is JavaScript method that means "Emphasize", another words change the view.

Answer (score 2):

here you can check how it's done in WordPress:

https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/26bda18a23174afb048afbe62296c76a62add542/wp-includes/category-template.php#L955

```
fontStep = (maxSize - minSize) / (maxCount - minCount);
fontSize = smallestFont + ( tagCount - minCount ) * fontStep;
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
max_word_count = 412  # should count from list
min_word_count = 44   # should count from list
difference = max_word_count - min_word_count
min_weight = 99 / difference * min_word_count

for each tag
    weight = 99 / difference * this_word_count - min_weight + 1
```

Which gave me weighed words between 1 and 100. It works perfectly for me at [znaci.net/arhiv](http://znaci.net/arhiv/).

DISCLAIMER: I am not good at math.