# Help understand the Algorithm for tag cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, tags, tag-cloud

I would like to understand the Algorithm/implementation of the tag cloud.

In tag cloud we get following tags(weight)

- Tag: tag is the string or term for search (or parent depending on type of cloud)
- Weight: frequency of numeric value for the tag

Now in tag cloud control only subset of the values are displayed with different font sizes. Consider a following sample space tag1(1)... tagx(2) and then few big tags tag2(4000). Now on UI i would like to show the tags (html elements with) fort size. With such a distinct sample one cannot end up showing the big 1000px font. This data needs to be processed to that I get slabs for point concentrations so that I get values say like following:

- for points concentration is move for 1 - 4 so that I divide it in 4 slabs each incement of 2 (1- 2px, 2- 4px, ... 4- 8px)
- 4000 and some K are less so I would like to make two slabs say (1000 - 2000 = 10px) and (2000 and above = 12px)

I am using ASP.NET C#. Please let me know how to achive this. I am really not good at mathematics (statistics). Please help me with this algorithm. Or link to maths/tutorial or good sample would help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717314/what-is-the-formula-to-calculate-the-font-size-for-tags-in-a-tagcloud found this one its nice thread discussed earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a downloadable O'Reilly ebook (40 something pages) called [Building Tag Clouds in Perl and PHP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596527945) that (from what I remember, it was a while ago) had a pretty good cover of the basics and also has (as the title implies) sample implementations in Perl and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly well explained example from [4 guys from Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150716/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/102506-1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for link, i am looking for the standers deviation with font weight which is http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/cloud.aspx link in the article. However its not there... do you know any other example which explains it with standard deviation

Answer (score 0):

I only say that to reduce complexity display only frequency beside tag name like here C# x 1000 .
But if you want to control font size with frequency .Make slab to restrict font size.Like

```
Frequency    Font Size
```

1--5          3px;
6--30         5px;
31-100        8px;
101-500       10px;
501-1000      12px;
<1000         14px;(restriction in final)

I dont know about asp.net But you can easliy implement this in PHP